# Model-level validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

How does one accomplish "model-level" validation as stated in Brad Wilson's post:

> Finally, if you want a validation to have access to multiple properties, then make it a model-level validation (so that it gets the entire model as the model parameter, rather than a single individual property value).

From http://forums.asp.net/p/1457591/3650720.aspx

I tried to do the following

```
[MyCustomValidation("SomeStuff")]
public class MyClass
{
     // properties
}
```

Breakpoints place in the `IsValid` override of `MyCustomValidation` trigger nothing, the code just continues. Breakpoints in the constructor of `MyCustomValidation` work, but nothing after that.

Is this not what `model-level validation` refers to?

### UPDATE:

dirtygopher's link to http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html shows model validation, the only issue is that the validation attributes are placed on the child properties of the parent class.

I'm looking for a way to place `validation-attributes` directly to the class as I demonstrated in my above example.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do class level validation? Thanks

Comment: i'm looking for the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good example for this in the RegisterModel that comes with the latest asp.net mv 2.

Look at the "PropertiesMustMatch" attribute and its usage.

Comment: Do you mean in the new project files?

Comment: Yes. It's in the Models folder.

Comment: Using VS 2010 and ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview thats why I didn't see this. Thanks.

Comment: this example is ok, but would rather prefer a blog post with proper descriptions

Answer (score 0):

Here is good post in Brad Wilson's blog 
[http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html.](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html)
I hope it will help you to understand model-level validation concept.

Comment: Thank you, this what I was looking for except the article only shows how to place validation on child models of parent models. I.E. I can put attributes on a Model child properties of a the parent model. I was hoping there would be a direct way to place attributes on an entire class not just its properties.

Comment: hey baddie, i am looking for the same thing. let me know if you find something.

Answer (score 0):

The is another answer to this question if you are using MVC3. This example creates an attribute that can be attached to a single property and make it dependend on another property by passing the property name and object value.

The result is more elegant because the attribute is attached to the object that is actually validated.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx